# Equation number format in Appendix

Tags: appendices

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,sort&compress]{elsarticle}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
bla bla bla...

\section{Formulation}

\appendix
\section{}
The advection eq is... 
\begin{equation}
u_t+au_x&=&0,
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

In Section formulation, Equation number is 1, and in Appendix Equation number is A.1.
 I want to continue  the  equation number in Appendix i.e numbers must be  2.
 I also tried

```
\begin{appendices}
...
\end{appendices}
```

then equation numbering is okay (i.e 2) but the main heading is Appendices instead of Appendix.
I want main section as a title 'Appendix' and equation number must be continue from previous section.

your cooperation will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Bibigul

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! There must be something else in your real code, because the posted code doesn't reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Bernard Thanx for pointing out my mistake. -:).

Comment: That's how `elsarticle` wants; if you want to submit a paper, do like *they* want. If it's not for a submission to Elsevier, don't use `elsarticle`.

Comment: @egreg: Thank you for the  correction, actually  i did not know that! i was just following the pattern of a published paper in elsarticle. -:). It is for a submission to elsarticle. Now i will go through the pattern what elsarticle. -:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `appendices` environment:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[page]{appendix}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Appendix}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
bla bla bla...

\begin{equation}
u_t+au_x=0,
\end{equation}
\section{Formulation}

\begin{appendices}
\section{Lalala}
The advection eq is...
\begin{equation}
u_t+au_x=0,
\end{equation}

\end{appendices}
```

[image]    \end{document}

Comment: still same output.

Comment: @Bibigul: Not at all:  see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you now its working. I haven't use \usepackage[page]{appendix} before.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution to getting consecutive equation numbering is to include the following two instructions in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}
```

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}

\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\begin{document}

\chapter{Main material}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{equation} 1+1=2 \end{equation}

\section{Formulation}
\begin{equation} 2+2=4 \end{equation}

\lipsum[1-20]  % 5 pages of filler text

\appendix

\chapter{Supplemental material}
\section{Hello}
\begin{equation} 3+3=6 \end{equation}

\lipsum[21-40]  % 5 pages of filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Chapters with `elsarticle`?

Comment: @egreg - The initial version of the OP's posting used the `report` document class, and that's the information I used for my answer. I don't know when (and by whom) the document class was changed to `elsarticle`.